# problem accessing the pytorch versions in conda environment

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

I am a user of a server with no root access.

I have installed `PyTorch version 1.9.0` in conda environment. But when I access it via Jupyter notebook, it still shows conda base version (`PyTorch 1.3.0`).

Although I am running the notebook from the environment. See screenshots for clarification.

[image]

[image]

My requirement is to run `PyTorch 1.9.0` version to run in the notebook rather than the current `1.3.0`

**Update:** I am using Jupyter via `SSH` (it is installed on the server, I am accessing via `SSH` client)

Comment: How do you start jupyter notebook? Start it after activating your `paper` env.

Comment: yes. i active it inside the "paper" via ssh.

Comment: can you try reinstalling jupyter in `paper` env: `conda install jupyter notebook`?

Comment: Have you checked where torch is being imported from (`print torch` after import?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After activating your target conda env, checl the location of jupyter:

```sh
conda activate paper
```

```sh
which jupyter
```

you have to see smth like

```sh
anaconda3/envs/paper/bin/jupyter
```

if not, for example you have this

```sh
anaconda3/bin/jupyter
```

That means you are using jupyter from base conda env, to fix this you have to install jupter inside your paper conda env

Comment: its here `/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/jupyter`

Comment: I get the problem. so I am not accessing jupyter from my `paper` environment. but I am getting from outside of it. let me install it in the environment and then try again.

Comment: It's working. thanks for the answer. upvoted and accepted. have a good day.